# Changing boundary conditions of PDE $2U_t + U_{xt} = 0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have an the equation $2U_t + U_{xt} = 0$. I found the general solution as $$U(x,t)=e^{-2x}P(t)+Q(x)$$ I have two questions about this:

1-find the solution for $U(x,0)=0$; $U_t(x,0)=e^{-2x}$

2-Is there a solution for $U(x,0)=0$; $U_t(x,0)=1$

I will appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please check [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for future questions. In particular, it is recommended to show your trials in the question statement and to use proper MathJax formatting.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, imposing the general solution in your boundary condition gives $$ e^{-2x}P(0)+Q(x)=0\\e^{-2x}P'(0)=e^{-2x} $$ then any $P, Q$ satisfying $ P'(0)=1, Q(x)=-P(0)e^{-2x} $ gives a solution.

For the second question, I don't think there exist a solution. If imposing your general solution to the second boundary condition, it gives $ P'(0)=e^{2x} $, which means that $P$ has to be a function of $x$. That's a contradiction.

Comment: My main problem is:  how can P′(0) be used in this question? it is not used anywhere. so what can this condition be used for?

Comment: For example, for the first question, $P'(0)$ has to equal 1, which means function $P(x)$ in solution can not be arbitrary.